# Paste From Clipboard Like MS Word

Tags: vb.net, clipboard

I appreciate if any one help me to tell me how to (paste from clipbord like MS Word) What I mean is if I selected a part of wep page contents text and picture, how to pate this contents from clipboard as it copped or formated.

this is my code

```
Private Sub Past_TxtBx_From_Cliboard_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Try
        RCSN.DetectUrls = True
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Clipboard.GetDataObject()
        If My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Html) Then
            Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html)
        ElseIf (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Html)) Then
            Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html)
        ElseIf (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Text)) Then
            Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text)
        ElseIf My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsImage() Then
            Clipboard.GetImage()
        End If
        RCSN.Paste()
        RCSN.Select()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ShowMsg(ex.Message & CurrentStickInfo(), "InfoSysMe (Stick Note)", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2, MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification, False)
    Finally
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        'RCSN.DetectUrls = False
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post unformatted code snippets. They are too hard to read. If you don't know how to use the editor, please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how. In this case, all you had to do was add an empty line. You could see that the code wasn't formatted but you submitted the question anyway.

Comment: sorry for interruption, second time I will care of that